# The system returned: (110) Connection timed out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

when i open my website it's shows

```
Connection to 173.0.139.119 failed.
The system returned: (110) Connection timed out
```

what is Problem? from my Web Application or Server ?

## note:

when i use proxy to open my site it's work fine

Comment: Opens fine to me (shows the default iis 7 page). Might not want to publicly expose that...

Comment: www.csn-tu.com please try to open this site ??

Comment: mmmm i think the problem from my isp ... thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi @HassanJuniedi, did you find out how to resolve this problem?